# convert 2-d list into dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary from three 2-d lists. For example:

```
list1 = [['Brand', 'Release Date', 'Related'], ['Structure', 'Screen', 'Photos', 'Videos']]

list2 = [['Brand', 'Aliases'], ['Release date', 'State'], ['Predecessor', 'Successors'], ['Size', 'Aspect Ratio', 'Weight', 'Usable surface', 'Materials', 'Colors', 'Origami']]

list3 = [['OppoSmartphones by Oppo', 'PAFM00, Oppo Find X Standard Edition'], ['June 2018, 10 months ago', 'On Sale'], ['Oppo Find 7', 'Oppo Reno'], ['74.2 mm x 156.7 mm x 9.4 mm', '19:9', '186 g', '87 %', 'Glass', 'Turquoise Violet', 'Print 3D Model']]
```

and I want the result as

```
{'Brand':{'Brand': 'OppoSmartphones by Oppo', 'Aliases': 'PAFM00, Oppo Find X Standard Edition'}, 'Release Date':{ 'Release date': 'June 2018, 10 months ago', 'State': 'On Sale'}, 'Related':{'Predecessor': 'Oppo Find 7', 'Successors': 'Oppo Reno'}}
```

Comment: What prevents you from doing that?

Comment: What happened to `['Structure', 'Screen', 'Photos', 'Videos']` in the output?

Comment: nothing happened.. I just don't want to show the result long.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
res = {}

for i in range(3):
    res[list1[0][i]] = {list2[i][0]:list3[i][0], list2[i][1]:list3[i][1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use loops, `dict()` and `zip()` to achieve that as in the following:

```py
list1 = [['Brand', 'Release Date', 'Related'], 
         ['Structure', 'Screen', 'Photos', 'Videos']]

list2 = [['Brand', 'Aliases'], ['Release date', 'State'],
         ['Predecessor', 'Successors'],
         ['Size', 'Aspect Ratio', 'Weight', 'Usable surface', 'Materials', 'Colors', 'Origami']]

list3 = [['OppoSmartphones by Oppo', 'PAFM00, Oppo Find X Standard Edition'],
         ['June 2018, 10 months ago', 'On Sale'],
         ['Oppo Find 7', 'Oppo Reno'],
         ['74.2 mm x 156.7 mm x 9.4 mm', '19:9', '186 g', '87 %', 'Glass', 'Turquoise Violet', 'Print 3D Model']]

d1 = {}
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list1[i])):
        #print(i,j)
        d1[list1[i][j]] = dict(zip(list2[j], list3[j]))


# to get this patter: dict = {list1[0][0]:{list2[0][0]:list3[0][0], list2[0][1]:list3[0][1]},
#                             list1[0][1]:{list2[1][0]:list3[1][0], list2[1][1]:list3[1][1]},
#                             list1[0][2]:{list2[2][0]:list3[2][0], list2[2][1]:list3[2][1]}}
d2 = {}
for i in range(len(list1[0])):
    if list1[0][i] not in d2.keys(): d2[list1[0][i]] = {}
    if list1[0][i] not in d2.keys(): d2[list1[0][i]] = {}

    d2[list1[0][i]][list2[i][0]] = list3[i][0] 
    d2[list1[0][i]][list2[i][1]] = list3[i][1] 


# if you want to apply the behaviour on all elements:
d3 = {}
for k in range(len(list1)): 
    for i in range(len(list1[k])):
        if list1[k][i] not in d3.keys(): d3[list1[k][i]] = {}
        if list1[k][i] not in d3.keys(): d3[list1[k][i]] = {}

        d3[list1[k][i]][list2[i][0]] = list3[i][0] 
        d3[list1[k][i]][list2[i][1]] = list3[i][1]
```

Output (d2):

```
{      'Brand': {'Aliases': 'PAFM00, Oppo Find X Standard Edition',
                 'Brand': 'OppoSmartphones by Oppo'},

     'Related': {'Predecessor': 'Oppo Find 7', 
                  'Successors': 'Oppo Reno'},

'Release Date': {'Release date': 'June 2018, 10 months ago',
                        'State': 'On Sale'}}
```

Comment: it's works fine..but not for all length of lists...mean...list1 having the length of 7 and list2 and list3 both having the length of 30

Comment: Then the described pattern is unclear. This only works for lists that have equal lengths.

Comment: list1= [['Brand', 'Release Date', 'Related']]
list2= [['Brand', 'Aliases'], ['Release date', 'State'], ['Predecessor', 'Successors']]
list3= [['OppoSmartphones by Oppo', 'PAFM00, Oppo Find X Standard Edition'], ['June 2018, 10 months ago', 'On Sale'], ['Oppo Find 7', 'Oppo Reno']]

Comment: pattern shiould be like this..dict = {list1[0][0]:{list2[0][0]:list3[0][0], list2[0][1]:list3[0][1]}, list1[0][1]:{list2[1][0]:list3[1][0], list2[1][1]:list3[1][1]}, list1[0][3]:{list2[2][0]:list3[2][0], list2[2][1]:list3[2][1]}}

Comment: My code gives you a good start on how to achieve that, you should be able to manipulate the indices to generate the desired behaviour.

Comment: I tried many algo...but not getting the output as expected.....please help me out

Comment: I think you made a typo. Is this the desired pattern? `dict = {list1[0][0]:{list2[0][0]:list3[0][0], list2[0][1]:list3[0][1]}, list1[0][1]:{list2[1][0]:list3[1][0], list2[1][1]:list3[1][1]}, list1[0][2]:{list2[2][0]:list3[2][0], list2[2][1]:list3[2][1]}}`

Comment: ur desired pattern is what i want.....but ur code behaviour on all elements d3 is not working...error I'm getting  d2[key[k][i]][table_sub_key[i][1]] = table_value[i][1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: can I mail you.

Comment: I am afraid I cannot help further. I suggest you post another question with better quality, clearer output, input behaviour and more about your data (which should be consistent). Good luck!